# Removing content in PencilKit

Tags: swift, ios13, ipados, pencilkit

When using PencilKit in iOS 13/iPadOS, how do you remove all content from the screen, or remove those content selected (via lasso)?

I can't find any functions in PKDrawing or PKCanvasView that do these?

Answer (score 9):

You can clear the drawing on the `PKCanvasView` by simply setting the `drawing` property equal to a new empty `PKDrawing`.

```
canvasView.drawing = PKDrawing()
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there anything else we can do with the selected (lasso) content?

Comment: That I have not used

Comment: Do you know how to undo/redo the drawing then? Since the whole PKDrawing is opaque.

Comment: this crashes for me as of beta 6